# Container becoming invisible when adding TextFields to it in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, textfield

I have a `Container` whitch needs to include two `TextField` where i can insert a product name and description. It is supposed to appear, and take its place, when a `FloatingActionButton` is pressed. This is actually working till I insert the `TextField` and I can't understand why.

This is the `Cointainer` code i wrote:

```
Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 4, bottom: 12),
  child: Container(
      width: 400,
      height: 125,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Color(0xFF00ABB3),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(widgetsRadius))
      ),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 20),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 25),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: const [
                  TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: "Name"
                    ),
                  ),
                  TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: "Description"
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  isButtonVisible = !isButtonVisible;
                });
              },
              child: Icon(Icons.arrow_circle_right, color: Colors.white,)
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
);
```

This is the result without the two `TextField`:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PxWNp.png]

This is the result with the two `TextField`:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttEY3.png]

The part of code where I'm actually using `isButtonVisible` (as requested from @Canada2000):

```
Scaffold(
  body: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 28, right: 28, top: 35, bottom: 10),
    child: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        AnimatedCrossFade(
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 150),
          sizeCurve: Curves.easeOutCirc,
          firstChild: _addProductButton(),
          secondChild: _emptyProductContainer(),
          crossFadeState: isButtonVisible ? CrossFadeState.showFirst : CrossFadeState.showSecond,
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Can you show the part of your code where you are using isButtonVisible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the Padding widget with `Expanded`, it will take the available width inside Row for TextField.

```
child: Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 20),
  child: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [
      Expanded(child:Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 25),
        child: Column(
```

Comment: Your solution is working perfectly fine. It's working even better with @MendelG 's solution

Answer (score 0):

If you run your code, you'll see this error in the output:

```
layoutConstraints.maxWidth < double.infinity
"An InputDecorator, which is typically created by a TextField, cannot have an unbounded width.\nThis happens when the parent widget does not provide a finite width constraint. For example, if the InputDecorator is contained by a Row, then its width must be constrained. An Expanded widget or a SizedBox can be used to constrain the width of the InputDecorator or the TextField that contains it."
```

This means that `TextField` is taking up an infinite width.

So, wrap your `TextFied` with a `SizedBox`:

```dart
SizedBox(
                      width: 100,
                      child: TextField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Name"),
                      ),
                    ),
```

Additionally, you might want to increase the height of the parent `Container()` in order to view all the widgets as they're being cut off.

Here's a complete runnable example:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 4, bottom: 12),
      child: Container(
        width: 400,
        height: 300,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Color(0xFF00ABB3),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15))),
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 20),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 25),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: const [
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 100,
                      child: TextField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Name"),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 100,
                      child: TextField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Description"),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      // isButtonVisible = !isButtonVisible;
                    });
                  },
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.arrow_circle_right,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ))
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
    ;
  }
}
```

Comment: Your solution is working, even in a better way with @YeasinSheikh 's one